# Internet disconnects every 15-20 minutes for about a minute and reconnects automatically

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, adsl2+

My internet connection is ADSL2+ and it was working fine for about 2 months till couple of days ago. Now I am facing problem of disconnection every 15-20 minutes. I have tried two different routers and both wi-fi and wired connection. Also, I have tried the same on laptop and desktop separately.

Following is the snapshot of ping www.google.co.in -t

```
Reply from 216.58.197.35: bytes=32 time=278ms TTL=43
Reply from 216.58.197.35: bytes=32 time=282ms TTL=43
Reply from 216.58.197.35: bytes=32 time=279ms TTL=43
Reply from 216.58.197.35: bytes=32 time=279ms TTL=43
Reply from 216.58.197.35: bytes=32 time=291ms TTL=43
Reply from 216.58.197.35: bytes=32 time=278ms TTL=43
Reply from 216.58.197.35: bytes=32 time=276ms TTL=43
Reply from 216.58.197.35: bytes=32 time=287ms TTL=43
Reply from 216.58.197.35: bytes=32 time=293ms TTL=43
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from <my_ip_address>: Destination host unreachable
Reply from 216.58.197.35: bytes=32 time=2310ms TTL=43
Reply from 216.58.197.35: bytes=32 time=285ms TTL=43
Reply from 216.58.197.35: bytes=32 time=287ms TTL=43
```

Note that I have masked my ip address as "my_ip_address". My ip address has not changed over the past 2 months, even though I have not requested for fixed ip address. Also, there are four lights on my router viz. power light, adsl line, wireless line and wired line. All four lights remain solidly lit even when this issue happens.

I have raised complaint with my service provider and they have not been able to solve this issue. Please let me know if there is anything I can do to resolve this apart from changing my broadband provider.

I have made a log of disconnections over the past hour and half. Disconnection timings 3:29pm 3:45pm 3:59pm 4:16 pm 4:30pm 4:45pm .

Answer (score 0):

It is a line quality problem. Theres not much you can do on your side except having good wires on the inside and using a phone filter to prevent using the phone from affecting your connectivity.
If those factors are met, the provider should check their side of the line near you.

Note that there is no reason for the IP address to change, so that is totally irrelevant to the topic. It will change, but not very often (mine on ADSL changed after 2 years the 1st time).

Comment: Thank you for your information. I had a different connection upto 2 months ago. I face disconnection issues in that about 9 months ago. At that time, when the disconnection happened, the adsl light would start blinking and the technician told that adsl connection is dropped as there is disturbance in the line. He changed splitter and re-did wire connections to fix the issue. But this time, adsl connection is not dropped by the router as adsl light is solid even when the connection is gone and the disconnects are happening like clockwork every 15 minutes or so.

Comment: It's still a disturbance but of a lower magnitude, low enough not to drop the connection completely.

Comment: Thank you Overmind. I'll share that information with the technician. He said he'll visit again tomorrow to take a look at this issue.

Comment: Since the disruption occurs at 15-20min interval, try to keep him there until it occurs so he can practically see for himself.